# Visual Studio Community 2015 сбрасывает настройки шрифтов

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

При работе в Visual Studio Community 2015 на ноутбуке, временами мои настройки шрифтов из *Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors* сбрасываются на дефолтные. Я заметил, что это происходит в процессе зарядки или разрядки батареи, похоже когда меняется режим энергосбережения. Можно как-то побороть такое нехорошее поведение?
[image: About Microsoft Visual Studio]

Comment: Перейти на другую IDE  (заодно узнаете, в VS проблема или нет)

Comment: @dIm0n На этом проекте используется vs2015. Перейти на другую не могу.
Однако в vs2019 такой проблемы нет.

Comment: [Нечто похожее](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33152595/13970074)